# Android addView работает не всегда

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток. Имеется

```
LinearLayout entryPageCommentsList
```

который я добавляю комментарии со страницы с помощью метода

```
private void addComment(final Map<String, Object> currentComment, int hashMapIndex) {
    View tmpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.entrypage_comment, null, false);
    ImageView entryCommentUSER_AVATAR = (ImageView) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.entryCommentUSER_AVATAR);
    TextView entryCommentUSER_NAME = (TextView) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.entryCommentUSER_NAME);
    TextView entryCommentDATE = (TextView) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.entryCommentDATE);
    TextView entryCommentRatingValue = (TextView) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.entryCommentRatingValue);
    TextView entryCommentMESSAGE = (TextView) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.entryCommentMESSAGE);
    imageLoader.displayImage(currentComment.get("USER_AVATAR").toString(), entryCommentUSER_AVATAR, displayImageOptions);
    entryCommentUSER_NAME.setText(currentComment.get("USER_NAME").toString());
entryCommentDATE.setText(timeAgo.getTimeAgo(currentComment.get("DATE").toString()));
    entryCommentRatingValue.setText(currentComment.get("COMMENT_RATING").toString());
    entryCommentMESSAGE.setText(currentComment.get("MESSAGE").toString());
    entryPageCommentsList.addView(tmpView);
}
```

Так же имеется

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> commentsData
```

Для хранения HashMap'ов, которые идут на вход методу addComment. Иногда приходится обновлять содержимое commentsData, допустим, когда изменяется рейтинг комментария. Тогда я пользуюсь таким кодом

```
entryPageCommentsList.removeAllViews();
for(int i = 0; i < commentsData.size(); i++)
    addComment(commentsData.get(i), i);
```

Странность пошла с того момента, как только приходится добавлять новый HashMap в commentsData:

```
public void updateComments() {
    if(commentsData.size() > 0) {
        commentsData.add(commentsData.get(commentsData.size() - 1));
        for(int i = commentsData.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
            commentsData.set(i, commentsData.get(i - 1));
    } else {
        commentsData.add(new HashMap<String, Object>());
    }
    commentsData.set(0, getNewCommentMap(response.get("HTML_CODE").toString()));
    entryPageCommentsList.removeAllViews();
    for(int i = 0; i < commentsData.size(); i++)
        addComment(commentsData.get(i), i);
}
```

Если в самом начале размер commentsData был больше 0, то метод addComment работает как надо, если же изначально в commentsData не было данных (commentsData всегда проинициализирован), то при добавлении данных в commentsData перестает адекватно работать addComment, а именно: новые view'шки не видны, хотя и показывает в логах, что entryPageCommentsList.getChildCount() == 1 (т.е. по сути в entryPageCommentsList добавлен один дочерний элемент, но его на экране смартфона не видно). Пробовал в методе updateComments в самом конце использовать entryPageCommentsList.invalidate(); entryPageCommentsList.requestLayout(); entryPageCommentsList.postInvalidate(); но ничего из перечисленного не помогает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что это за велосипед?
почему бы не использовать ListView ?

Comment: Возможно у вас в TextView заданы "wrap_content" по ширине и высоте и, когда вы добавляете пустые значения в них, то у них ширина с высотой нулевые становятся.

Comment: @Barmaley, не ищем легких путей =) вспомнил про контакт

Comment: @Роман Захаров, у меня помимо комментариев еще дофигища текста, изображений и прочего. Какой там ListView...
@ЮрийСПб, пустых значений нету, есть пустой ArrayList, который заполняется по мере загрузки комментариев))

Comment: @PhoEn-X в ListView можно добавлять все что угодно, главное разобраться в этом. 
Советую пойти в сторону ListView. То что вы выбрали не правильно. Если элементов будет больше 100 в списке, у вас начнет жутко лагать, я вас уверяю.

Comment: @Andreich, спасибо, конечно, но я так надеялся больше не сталкиваться с ListView, в котором много различных элементов (намучался уже). Так же у меня внутри содержится ImageLoader, когда я буду прокручивать свой список вниз, тогда ImageLoader будет снова и снова прогружать изображения в комментариях, что как раз-таки и создает лаги.

Comment: @PhoEn-X, тем не менее, в данном случае правильно использовать именно `ListView`, а то, что вы сделали — страшноватый и некачественный костыль, который приведёт к ряду проблем при большом количестве элементов. Советую таки посидеть, почитать документацию и осилить `ListView`, адаптеры и сопутствующее.

Comment: @falstaf, ну, один уже написал... Уже второй пишу)) Этот будет просто монстром)) Вот только что делать с лагами при подгрузке изображений, когда прокручиваешь список... (ImageLoader асинхронно загружает изображения, но задает их в главном потоке).

Comment: @PhoEn-X, ну так кладите загруженные изображения в кэш, незачем их каждый раз загружать заново. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: @falstaf, в том, что при загрузке из кеша все равно лагает. Пробовал так в миничате выводить аватары пользователей, уж лучше бы и не начинал.
@falstaf, 1 раз пролагается и все, дальше без проблем. Документацию в первую очередь читал.

Comment: @PhoEn-X, странное вы что-то рассказываете. То есть загрузка изображений для всех элементов сразу не лагает, а для 4-6 элементов `ListView` — лагает. Очевидно же, что вы что-то делаете не так. Может всё же документацию да сэмплы почитать, не?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй место Wrap_content  fill_parent;